# NSURLSession from macos Sharing Extension

Tags: macos, nsurlsession, macos-app-extension

I'm getting this error in the `func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {` URLSessionDataDelegate method:

> error=Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1 “unknown error”
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.example.com/,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=unknown error,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.example.com/})

Very similar code works perfectly from an application, but I'm trying to write an Sharing App Extension which uploads to a webserver.

I'm using URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier:"...") same as my desktop application.

Why do I get erorr -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the `com.apple.security.network.client` entitlement in the `entitlements` file.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW9